# To run app in background for long time in iphone

Tags: iphone

Hi I want to run my app in background until I quit it.For that I have used the code below

```
 bgTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [application endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;

            });
        }];
```

but it quits after particular time.Can any one guide me to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You don't!

Apple will allow you to complete a lengthy operation, but it is not ment to keep your app running. This will drain your battery.

There are three kind of background running apps support by Apple: Audio player, VOIP client and location based apps. Location based apps will only receive major location updates and only one audio player can run at a time.

Mis use of the background mode will get you app rejected.

Comment: More background modes? Xcode only has: App plays audio, App registers for location updates and App provides Voice over IP services.

Comment: external-accessory and bluetooth-central also exist. May well be more :)

Comment: @Martin did not know that, thanks for the information. Did find out that there is also a `newsstand` mode.

Comment: Thanks to all...I need to check the time for every seconds in background is it possible.

Comment: Thanks rckoenes....Can u please tell me how to set local notification for weekdays,week end and selected days only

Answer (score 1):

wont work this way. your application need to support one of the background modes in a proper way

Comment: Thanks to all...I need to check the time for every seconds in background is it possible.