# How can I update user location continuously?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

Is there any way to perform continuous background location update in iOS11?

I've read the official documentation, there are two ways to do location update function:

1. Standard location update (immediate update)
2. Significant change (500 meters or above)

I tried the first one, but it can only last for 20 mins in average.
Should I just use the second way to accomplish the function or combine two ways? The document said second method will automatically wake up your app when new location data arrives no matter app is suspended or terminated.
Can I use this feature to perform an immediate update?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637922/location-tracking-stops-after-a-while-when-app-is-in-the-background) might be related.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the solution is work for me, at least now it can survive over 20 mins

Comment: Glad to help! So I will flag the question as a duplication...

Comment: Hi, i have another problem now@@ after i followed the article that you posted and tested it, i find that it cannot run forever in the background@@ it can only survive 18 ~ 30 hrs